# Programa crashea al usar scanf en matriz de float

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en c. Estoy viendo el tema de estructuras y punteros. El siguiente programa debería crear una estructura con un puntero a puntero de tipo float y guardar numeros en la misma. Sin embargo, la función *captura* crashea cuando el numero de filas es menor al de columnas. No logro encontrar cual sea el motivo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o dirección que pudieran darme. Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matriz
{
    int filas;
    int columnas;
    float **array;
} Matriz;

float **creaMatriz(int, int);
Matriz captura();
void mostrar(Matriz*);
void libera(Matriz*);

int main(void)
{
    Matriz *A;
    Matriz *B;

    A = (Matriz*)calloc(1, sizeof(Matriz));
    B = (Matriz*)calloc(1, sizeof(Matriz));

    A[0] = captura();
    B[0] = captura();

    mostrar(A);
    mostrar(B);

    libera(A);
    libera(B);

    getchar()
    return 0;
}

float ** creaMatriz(int filas, int columnas)
{   
    int i;  
    float ** X = (float* *)calloc(filas, sizeof(float *));

    for (i = 0; i<columnas; i++)
        X[i] = (float *)calloc(columnas, sizeof(float));

    return X;
}

Matriz captura()
{
    int F = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    Matriz X = {0,0,NULL};

    printf("Filas matriz:");
    scanf("%d", &F);
    printf("Columnas matriz:");
    scanf("%d", &C);

    X.array = creaMatriz(F, C);
    X.filas = F;
    X.columnas = C;

    for (i = 1; i<=X.filas; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j<=X.columnas; j++)
        {
            printf("Introdusca valor en posicion %d %d : ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%f", &X.array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return X;
}

void mostrar(Matriz *AB)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i<AB[0].filas; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<AB[0].columnas; j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f ", AB[0].array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return;
}

void libera(Matriz *AB)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<AB[0].filas; i++)
    free(AB[0].array[i]);

    free(AB);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si creas un arreglo con, digamos 10 elementos, los mismos se encontrarán disponibles en el rango [0,9]. Entonces, si tu indicas que el número de elementos es 10 no puedes plantearte iterar sobre el rango [1,10] porque entonces vas a intentar acceder a memoria que no te pertenece.

Tus bucles son incorrectos:

```
for (i = 1; i<=X.filas; i++)
```

Lo correcto sería (también aplicable al bucle de `j` anidado):

```
for (i = 0; i<X.filas; i++)
```

Que es similar a lo que ya estás aplicando en la función `mostrar`.

Comment: que torpe de mi, muchas gracias. Pero, aun al corregir los bucles, me sigue tirando error cuando el valor de filas es mas grande que el de columnas, alguna idea de que podría estar pasando? gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @user35102 Revisa que los dos bucles estén bien... el primero debería atacar las filas y el segundo las columnas y verifica que los rangos de iteración sean correctos

Comment: oh ya vi el otro error, el problema esta en la función creaMatriz, el bucle que aloca memoria para cada fila del arreglo tomaba como condición a columnas cuando debería de tomar a filas. Gracias por tu ayuda y tus respuestas, me as ayudado mucho.